# (.getBoundingClientRect().height are giving wrong values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am trying this code in an angular project but not working, although it does in an HTML template
the main goal of the code is to make the div to fit with its content

```
function resizeGridItem(x,item){
    console.log('resizeGridItem')
    grid = $(".grid")[0];
    // console.log(grid)
    rowHeight = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-auto-rows'));
    console.log('rowHeight '+rowHeight)
    rowGap = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(grid).getPropertyValue('grid-row-gap'));
    console.log('rowGap '+rowGap)
    // console.log('item is ')
    // console.log(item)
    rowSpan = Math.ceil((item.querySelector('.card-content').getBoundingClientRect().height+rowGap)/(rowHeight+rowGap));
    console.log('getBoundingClientRect '+item.querySelector('.card-content').getBoundingClientRect().height)
    console.log('rowSpan '+rowSpan)
    item.style.gridRowEnd = "span " + rowSpan;
}
//
function resizeAllGridItems(){
    console.log('resizeAllGridItems')
    allItems = document.getElementsByClassName("card");;
    console.log(allItems.length)
    for(x=0;x<allItems.length;x++){
        resizeGridItem(x,allItems[x]);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    window.onload = resizeAllGridItems();
})
```

as you can see i tried to print the results 
both rowGap and rowHeight have the same value in both projects
but the final one rowSpan and the query selector height are not!

the HTML Code

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content show">
            <div class="card-header">
              <img src="user1.jpg">
              <div class="title">
                  <div class="publisher">
                      <p>Publisher name</p>
                      <p>1 hrs</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img class="photothumb" src="cake4.jpg"/>
            <div class="card-interaction">
                <span>30 Comments | 512 Views </span>
                <span><img src="assets/images/like.png"> 61 </span>
                <span><img src="assets/images/dislike.png"> 61 </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-content show">
            <div class="card-header">
              <img src="user1.jpg">
              <div class="title">
                  <div class="publisher">
                      <p>Publisher name</p>
                      <p>1 hrs</p>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <img class="photothumb" src="cake.jpg"/>
            <div class="card-interaction">
                <span>30 Comments | 512 Views </span>
                <span><img src="assets/images/like.png"> 61 </span>
                <span><img src="assets/images/dislike.png"> 61 </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

photo of the view will be added if necessary

Comment: Have you considered trying to do the same thing with some css wrangling instead of  a javascript-based solution?

Comment: @iPhoenix actually no!
i am going to try

Comment: @iPhoenix could you help me to write one?